# How to make firebase storage only available to users of my website

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using Firebase realtime database and storage in my website i want to make files uploaded to Firebase storage can be opened only in my website.
for example if you inspect the code and got the url of a file you wont be able to open it with direct url in new tab or embed it to your website or download it.
can this be done with Firebase ? and how ? 
thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create an `uid` for each user when he's create his account, then store to this `uid`

Comment: Have a look at the doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/?authuser=0 and in particular https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/user-security

Answer (score 0):

This can't be enforced.  If you generate a [download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url) for a file in Cloud Storage, it will be accessible by anyone with that URL from anywhere on the internet.

If you need to control access to a file in Cloud Storage, don't use download URLs.  Instead, use Firebase Authentication along with the Cloud Storage for Firebase SDK to download files that are protected by [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/) that allow access for a given user who is logged in.  This is the only way to limit downloads.

Comment: In this case the user can't retrieve the file url if he opens the browser developer tools?

Comment: If you are talking about viewing source, no, there will be no URL in the source if you use the SDK to download.